# PHP htmlentities() and htmlspecialchars() are broken / do not work

Tags: php, cakephp, htmlspecialchars

I have used these two functions in the past,and they worked fine. I'm developing a CakePHP application and for some reason use of either of these functions does NOTHING. I've setup a simple test, and I can't believe it's returning true:

```
$loc_title = htmlentities($location['locations']['title']);

if(htmlentities($location['locations']['title']) === $location['locations']['title']){

    echo "htmlentaties is broken.";
}
```

What could cause these functions to stop working properly?

Comment: note that you should be using a method similar to h() - I called it ent() for example - which will have the correct encoding passed as third param.

Comment: is $loc_title significant to your question?

Comment: nevermind.. I see you have your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Consider changing

```
htmlentities($location['locations']['title'] === $location['locations']['title'])
```

to

```
htmlentities($location['locations']['title']) === $location['locations']['title']
```

for instance ;-)

Beause what you're doing here is you escape entities in the result of comparison of title with itself. Which most likely evaluates to true.

Comment: The reason I screwed up copy/pasting is because I was testing htmlentatites vs htmlspecialchars. My bad. I just updated my comment to properly reflect the code that I'm using. I'm 100% certian that the function is NOT escaping any chars, because I'm iterating over this array to create an HTML string javascript variable. I keep getting JS errors because of ill placed double and single quotes.

Comment: Your update introduces unbalanced parenthesis. If you're escaping strings for use as a javascript string, you better look at `json_encode` instead.

Comment: See: `php > var_dump( htmlentities('<">') );
string(14) "&lt;&quot;&gt;"`

Comment: I tried adding your text elsewhere in my code and it worked as expected. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: I figured it out and I feel really really stupid... I needed to use addslashes() instead of htmlspecialchars/entities()

Comment: Yes, but again, do consider json_encode. When applied to string, it's exactly what you need.